# Can a document be stored against a Community User?

Tags: community, document, file-storage

Suppose I have 10000 Community Users, can I store a document for each of them? The content of the document would be miscellaneous info, logs etc.., . If so what are the file size limitations? Also I would like to know the difference between Files and Documents.

Comment: Bharath, I see 3 sort of separate questions there which makes your question(s) harder to answer in a single answer and less useful for others in the future. Could you consider updating your question to a single specific question ? If needed you can always ask a new different questions for the separate things you're wondering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this with Salesforce.com standard features, attachments area might be useful. In this case, you will probably create an object that holds the attachments for these users and use the sharing rules to provide access to the object as well as its attachments. This may not prove to be the best solution as the file size limit is usually 25MB and the storage can become very expensive once you reach a limit.

You can also consider Salesforce.com files feature but there is not really much of organization with the files and I'm not even sure if it will be easy enough to maintain this.

You can use third party tools from AppExchange. [Box.com](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001qNeKEAU) is one that can be used but I bet it will be super expensive and hard to work with considering 10000 users.

Another AppExchange solution, [S-Drive](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingdetail?listingId=a0N30000001SWUTEA4) is a good option as this is a solution built on Salesforce.com and it includes community support as well as sharing features. You can either create ad-hoc folders and share with individual community users or use it similar to the attachments of Salesforce.com (such as Case file attachments) and use the standard Salesforce.com sharing rules to handle access to content. It is also cheaper than other solutions as the content is stored on Amazon.